# Persisting data on "List" page while visiting "Details" page

Tags: angularjs

I'm an angular newbie so please bear with me.

I've been trying to do this for a while and can't figure out how to do it.

I have three (1 abstract parent) states, like so:

```
.state('recipes', {
    url: '/recipes',
    abstract: true,
    template: '<ui-view/>'
  })
  .state('recipes.listing', {
    url: '/listing',
    templateUrl: '/modules/recipes/client/views/recipes.listing.html',
    controller: 'RecipesController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    data: {
      pageTitle: 'Recipes'
    }
  })
  .state('recipes.details', {
    url: '/details',
    templateUrl: '/modules/recipes/client/views/recipes.details.html',
    controller: 'RecipesDetailsController',
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  });
```

From the Listing page, the user has a list they can select from.. Upon selecting from the list they visit the Details page via $state.go().  Now when they press the "back" button, they go back to the Listing page but all the data that they queried is now gone.  The only way I can think of doing it is converting the pages into views and inserting them into 1 state, and then showing/hiding them, but I felt this was not the Angular way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a service to store whatever is needed to replicate the view when user returns

Comment: @charlietfl This is another solution I've come across.  I'm feeling like it might be another good route.  I'm not sure why but I was hoping for a more elegant, 'Angular' solution

Comment: That is the angular way. When you leave a view the controller instance is gone but a service is a singleton

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use routes in RESTfull way. For Example your listing page route can be :

```
.state('recipes', {
    url: '/recipes',
    templateUrl: '/modules/recipes/client/views/recipes.listing.html',
    controller: 'RecipesController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    data: {
      pageTitle: 'Recipes'
    }
})
```

And for details route :

```
  .state('recipes.details', {
    url: '/recipes/:recipeID/details',
    templateUrl: '/modules/recipes/client/views/recipe.details.html',
    controller: 'RecipesDetailsController',
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  });
```

And your listing page you can add id based link to reach each of the item's details page. If you use table, your table body should be seen something like this :

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat= "recipe in recipes">
        <td><a ng-href="#!/recipes/{{::recipe._id}}/details"></a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I don't understand how this solves the problem.  This looks like we've simply re-organized the pages.  I am not sure this solves the problem I raised

Comment: This encounters that when selecting an item from list, it goes that item's details page because the route can be constructed for selected item uniquely, not hiding other thins in one state. (more angular way I think)